# KStream/KTable leftjoin after transform() leads to : StreamsException: A serializer is not compatible to the actual key or value type

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I wrote the following DSL:

```
myStream
        .leftJoin(myKtable, new MyValueJoiner())
        .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(),MyObject.serde()))
        .reduce((v1, v2) -> v2, Materialized.as("MY_STORE"))
        .toStream()
```

This works correctly, the leftjoin() is ok, and the reduce() is well materialized as a state store on which I can perform put() and delete().

However if I wrote **MyTranformer** class implementing the **Transformer** interface and do the following:

```
myOtherStream.transform(() -> new MyTransformer<>(), MY_STORE)
        .leftJoin(myOtherKTable, new MyOtherValueJoiner<>());
```

Then I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: com.MyObject). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:94)
```

From the Javadoc, [leftjoin](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#leftJoin-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueJoiner-) seems to use the default serdes, and it seems there is no way to force usage of custom serdes, as it is however possible for other operands.

However, if I do something else than a leftjoin() after transform(), like a mapValue() or filter(), it works as expected. But as soon as I perform a leftjoin() I encounter the cast exception.

Can I use a leftjoin() after a transform() ?

Why in the first case the leftjoin() works even if the doc says it uses the default serdes, whereas with the transformer it fails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I simply missed in the Javadoc the leftJoin() taking a [Joined](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Joined.html) argument to specify the serdes to be used:

```
myOtherStream.transform(() -> new MyTransformer<>(), MY_STORE)
    .leftJoin(myOtherKTable, new MyOtherValueJoiner<>(), Joined.with(JoinedKey.serde(), JoinedValue.serde(), JoinedValueOutput.serde()));
```